# Whom/Who do I look like?

Tags: whom

Is "Whom do I look like" the 'proper' way of saying "Who do I look like?"
I know that second option is the most used one, but still

Comment: ...more specifically (when followed by ***do***) -  Possible duplicate of [Why is it “Who do you help?,” not “Whom do you help?”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457572/why-is-it-who-do-you-help-not-whom-do-you-help)

Comment: If you insist on using "whom", the proper structure is "Like whom do I look" anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -

And you can tell that it is the right way bc if you turn the sentence around you would say, "Do I look like him?" Or "Do I look like her?" Whom stands in for Him / Her and Who stands in for He / She.
I believe He / She / Who are called subject pronouns.
And Him / Her / Whom are object pronouns.